# How to convert a list of lists into a bidimensional array in Java

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I came up with below solution, not sure if Type:safety warnings can be removed using something else.

```
BiFunction<List<List<T>>, Class<T>,T[][]> toArray = (list,type) ->
{
    T a[][] = (T[][]) Array.newInstance(type,
            list.size(), list.get(0).size());
    IntStream.range(0, a.length)
    .forEach(i -> {
        a[i]=(T[]) list.get(i).toArray();
    });
    return a;
};
```

Also, if this could be improved with one single pipeline I would appreciate the solution.

Comment: `List.toArray()` without an argument will always return `Object[]` - you'll need to create proper instances for the components as well, not just for the larger array. Where do you get your warnings?

Comment: sorry, but I don't understand what you want to do exactly? convert `List<List<T>>` to `T[][]`

Comment: I get the warnings on the first assignment, also I'd like to say that I had to rewrite the method when I tested this on Integer matrix , so now I use below `BiFunction<List<List<T>>, Class<T>,T[][]> toArray = (list,type) ->
 {
  T a[][] = (T[][]) Array.newInstance(list.get(0).get(0).getClass(),
    list.size(), list.get(0).size());
  IntStream.range(0, list.size())
  .forEach(i -> {
    IntStream.range(0, list.get(0).size())
    .forEach(j -> {
     a[i][j]=list.get(i).get(j);
    });
  });
  return a;
 }; `

Comment: YCF_L yes that's what I'm looking for, fyi, the code works but I'd like a more elegant way of doing this using streams and maps, and don't have to use the forEach statement which cannot be run on parallel stream

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have two suggestions, in both, convert the from List to List  iterating List of List and adding each element as T[] in a new list.

Use Array.newInstance only for create auxiliar objects and add @SuppressWarnings annotation

```
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <T> T[][] toArray(List<List<T>> list, Class<T> type) {

    T aux[] = (T[]) Array.newInstance(type, 0);
    T auxBi[][] = (T[][]) Array.newInstance(type, 0, 0);

    List<T[]> newList = new ArrayList<>();
    list.forEach(e -> newList.add(e.toArray(aux)));

    T[][] newBi = newList.toArray(auxBi);

    return newBi;
}
```

or

add auxliars as parameters instead of *type*

```
public static <T> T[][] toArray(List<List<T>> list, T aux[], T auxBi[][]) {

    List<T[]> newList = new ArrayList<>();
    list.forEach(e -> newList.add(e.toArray(aux)));

    T[][] newBi = newList.toArray(auxBi);

    return newBi;

}
```

Comment: Appreciate this answer, this gave me an idea of what I was looking to achieve.

Comment: Solution above using a stream pipeline `public BiFunction<List<List<T>>,Class<T>, T[][]> toArr = (list,type)-> list.stream().map(row -> row.toArray((T[]) Array.newInstance(type, 0))).collect(Collectors.toList()).toArray((T[][]) Array.newInstance(type, 0, 0)); `